# Google People API not returning all photo sources

Tags: google-people-api

[Getting](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) a person through the Google People API does not seem to return profile sources that are connected using a phone number, as opposed to an email address.

I have several contacts that when viewed through [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com) have a photo coming from their connected Google+ profile, stated to have been found via the contact's phone number. However when requesting the contacts through Google People the photo or source (the Google+ profile) is not returned in the response.

When doing the same for contacts where the profile is stated to have been found via an email address the photo and profile is returned in the response.

How do I get a contact's photo when the photo comes from a Google+ profile connected via a phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug with getting profile data connected through phones, that should be fixed now.